# Spark SQL - PostgreSQL JDBC Classpath Issues

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, apache-spark

I’m having an issue connecting Spark SQL to a PostgreSQL data source. I’ve downloaded the Postgres JDBC jar and included it in an uber jar using sbt-assembly.

My (failing) source code:
https://gist.github.com/geowa4/a9bc238ca7c372b95267.

I’ve also tried using `sqlContext.jdbc()` preceded with `classOf[org.postgresql.Driver]` as well. It appears the driver can access the Driver just fine.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

SimpleApp.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val commits = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.59.103:5432/postgres",
      "dbtable" -> "commits",
      "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver"))
    commits.select("message").show(1)
  }
}
```

simple.sbt:

```
name := "simple-project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.1" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"
```

output (Edited):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:219)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:697)
        at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:17)
        at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

EDIT: I changed the Scala version to 2.10.5 and the output changed to this. I feel like I'm making progress.

Comment: I think my issue might be that I was compiling with Scala 2.11. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211

Comment: Nope, that just got me to another error which seems to be a classpath issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem with general problem with JDBC, where the primordial classloader must know about the jar.  In Spark 1.3 this can be addressed using the `SPARK_CLASSPATH` option as described here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

In Spark 1.4, this should be fixed by [#5782](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5782).

Comment: Thanks for the reply; it's great to see this will be resolved soon. I thought if I made an uber-jar including the PostgreSQL driver, I would avoid that issue.

Comment: I was able to get it to work locally with these commands: `sbt package` and `spark-submit --driver-class-path ~/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.3-1102-jdbc41/postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar `. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

1) Copy file into your jar location

2) Add jar in path as follows

```
spark-submit    --jars /usr/share/java/postgresql-jdbc.jar    --class com.examples.WordCount  .. .. ..
```